# Will JSP Modification remain after Tomcat restart?

Tags: tomcat, solaris, jsp

A war file is deployed in Tomcat 6 on Solaris 10. antiResourceLocking is not set to true. A change is to be made to a JSP in the application folder(exploded from the war file). No restart is made.

If Tomcat is restarted inadvertently, will the JSP change made earlier still be around or would it overwritten from the war?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will stay the same. The war is only exploded once.

Of course you can delete the war file to be on the safe side, it's not needed any more.